# converting query to list (not working) asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I am trying to create a query whose results will be stored in a ViewModel.  When I try to assign the query variable to the ViewModel's method, I get the following error:  "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Iqueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.  An explicit-conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".
I tried changing my ViewModel's methods to be of type Iqueryable instead of List which worked but then I couldn't use a foreach loop in my view to loop through my model so I changed it back to List.  I tried doing ToList() after my query but that didn't work either.  Any suggestions/hints/tips are greatly appreciated.  Below is my controller code and my ViewModel code.

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using KU_PLAN_DEV.Models;

namespace KU_PLAN_DEV.ViewModels
{
public class TrackViewModel
{
    public List<string> TRACK_INFO { get; set; }
    public List<string> GEN_ED_HEAD { get; set; }
}
}
```

Controller method:

```
 public ActionResult DisplayTrackSheet(string trackButton)
    {
        var db = new KuPlanEntities();

        var trackProgNum = (from info in db.TRACK_INFO
                            where info.degreeName == trackButton
                            select info.progNum).ToString();

        var trackVerNum = (from info in db.TRACK_INFO
                           where info.degreeName == trackButton
                           select info.versionNum).ToString();

        /*var queryTrack = (from tracks in db.GEN_ED_HEAD
                          where tracks.)*/

        var trackData = (from trackInfo in db.TRACK_INFO
                         where trackInfo.progNum == trackProgNum
                         && trackInfo.versionNum == trackVerNum
                         select trackInfo);

        var trackDisplayMod = new TrackViewModel
        {
            TRACK_INFO = trackData
        };

        return View(trackDisplayMod);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var trackDisplayMod = new TrackViewModel
    {
        TRACK_INFO = trackData.ToList()
    };
```

What error do you get when you make that change?